# How to access the subfolder in a R package

Tags: r, package

This question seems like a duplicate but I couldn't understand the answers given in other threads.

So, my package structure looks like this:

```
- analysis
- data
- man
- R 
- DESCRIPTION
- NAMESPACE
```

I have included a `R file` inside the analysis folder. This file is not a file with functions but has a code that uses the data in the package. Is it possible to access the file that is inside the analysis folder after the package is installed?

The reason I have included R analysis file is because I wanted this package to store everything from data to my analysis. Not sure if this is the best approach to work with project.

Comment: `system.file(package = "packagename")` gives you the base directory of an installed package. You can also look for a specific file name under that base directory (recursively).

Comment: i create a separate r package for projects (or groups of similar projects) highly recommend

Comment: @rawr That's what I am tryting to do. This is for a specific project. So, I wanted to store data and R code that has some analysis using the data.

Comment: you need put extra things under the `/inst` folder, eg, `/inst/figures/`, `/inst/analyses`, etc. `/data` is mostly for Rdata files, I put raw/clean data (csv, xlsx, etc) under `inst/extdata/whatever`

Comment: @rawr Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for. Now, I can access the files. Thanks.